# How do i return column that contains images

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a widget that returns column of widgets, my code is like this

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {

  String productImage;
  String productName;
  double productPrice;

  ProductList({this.productImage, this.productPrice, this.productName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(image: Image.asset(productImage)),
          Text(productName),
          Text(productPrice.toString())

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Im getting error on line 16 which is  `Image(image: Image.asset(productImage)),`

the error message is `The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'.`
How do i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happens because u trying put a `Image` inside other `Image`. This is my suggestion:

```dart
class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {

  String productImage;
  String productName;
  double productPrice;

  ProductList({this.productImage, this.productPrice, this.productName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(productImage),
          Text(productName),
          Text(productPrice.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I cant  accept your answer as useful because i don't have enough reputation, i will accept it once i can.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `Image` widget that way, to display an asset image just use `Image.asset(productImage)`. Right now you're putting an image `Image.asset()`, inside the `Image()` widget, hence the error.